# How to fetch data from mysql to ckeditor textarea?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, ckeditor, textarea

> I am using ckeditor package with core php for my project.User will 
>   input his post into textarea that is with ckeditor. So user can use 
>   toolbar of ckeditor. and user can store his data in database as 
>   html.Now i want to fetch data from table as user saved into db.But 
>   problem is its not fetching data as html.its showing data without
>   html. suppose If i store data as "*Hi *How are You**"  on  storing
>   data it fails to store space between words. and as expected  when i
>   fetch data it shows data without space.

I am using jquery ajax method to store data into database:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var comment_data = CKEDITOR.instances["new_reply"].getData();

  var dataString = 'comment_data='+comment_data';
  alert(dataString);
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:"add_data.php",
    success:function(data) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
  });
```

On console dataString it shows me result with html tags and data as it is i am typing in ckeditor. But its not stores if i add long spaces in between words.

Comment: `var dataString = 'comment_data='+comment_data';` has an errornous end quote

Comment: please ignore typo

Answer (score 0):

At the time of saving the ckeditor value use the serialize method. This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing their type and structure

```
$comment_data = serialize($_POST['comment_data']);
```

To display the ckeditor data form database use unserialize().

```
$content = unserialize($row["comment_data"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your data in an object:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:{
        comment_data: comment_data
    },
    url:"add_data.php",
    success:function(data) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
  });
```

and get your data in server-side:

```
comment_data: $_POST['comment_data']
```